# SQL join, get result where 2 values are different

Tags: sql

I got to write a SQL query where I get the `ProductNr` value if 2 other values are different.

I got this query at the moment, but it doesn't work...

```
SELECT 
    Table1.productNr, Table1.info2 
FROM 
    Table1 
INNER JOIN 
     ON Table1.productNr = Table2.productNR 
WHERE 
    Table1.info2 <> Table2.info2
```

Comment: What DBMS or you using?

Comment: Ahh... the infamous "it doesn't work" error...

Comment: Both the comment and your username are funny @LittleBobbyTables haha

Comment: Im sorry for that, got a error in FROM syntax,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You miss Table2 in `FROM`

```
SELECT Table1.productNr, Table1.info2 
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.productNr=Table2.productNR 
WHERE Table1.info2 <> Table2.info2
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an error in your SQL.  This should work:

```
 SELECT 
      Table1.productNr, 
      Table1.info2 
  FROM Table1 
  INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.productNr=Table2.productNR 
  WHERE Table1.info2 <> Table2.info2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table1.productNr, Table1.info2 
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.productNr=Table2.productNR 
WHERE Table1.info2 <> Table2.info2
```

Your query was incorrect. After **Join** you must follow table name on which you are making join.